# jquery-ui tooltip disable tooltip for disabled elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with jquery tooltip. This happens especially in jquery datepicker plugin. When I hover over previous month icon, the tooltip is shown, but its not hidden even if I close the datepicker widget. This happens only when the previous icon is disabled in datepicker plugin. I could see the below lines of code in jquery-ui.js. Line number 12269

```
// Disabled elements have inconsistent behavior across browsers (#8661)
        items: "[title]:not([disabled])",
        position: {
            my: "left top+15",
            at: "left bottom",
            collision: "flipfit flip"
        },
```

The line

```
items: "[title]:not([disabled])",
```

is supposed to disable tooltip for elements that are disabled if am correct. Still I could see the tooltip for disabled previous icon in jquery datepicker widget. I'm using IE8, but this problem persists even in chrome.

Here are the steps with which I faced this problem.

1. Hover over datepicker previous month button(its disabled)
2. Select a date and it closes the datepicker widget, but the tooltip is not hidden.

This problem occurs only for elements that are disabled. How do I overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies or not, but are you sure you're just not seeing the `default` action browsers provide when you hover?

Comment: No, am not seeing the default action. I have tried it by not initializing the jquery ui tooltip, the problem does not occur in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple trick for this issue:

```
// Remove tool-tips from all disabled elements
$('input:disabled').attr('title', '');
```

Comment: Am still getting it. I tried inside the document ready function, still of no use.